# Primary Key Duplication Exception

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0, exception

I am working on a project in C# using sql server as a data base. So the problem is there is a algo in my project which returns a single value every time; which is saved to the database (as my project requirement). If the algo repeats a value, that will also save to the database which is not required (duplication) and cause some problems. I need help to overcome the problem that a unique value saves only once when it occurs; no repetition in database. I tried to make that column a primary key, but then I found primary key violation exception.

Comment: Post the code you use to save the value to the database.  Then we can change it to suit your needs.  Such as only inserting if the value doesn't already exist, and/or confirming if the value was inserted or the value was already present.

Answer (score 4):

Just use an EXISTS query either in-line or in a stored procedure

Your query procedure can check if the row already exists

Edit: Aha sorry forgot the NOT, that would be stupid :D

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT UniqueValue FROM UniqueValuesTable WHERE UniqueValue = @NewValue)
  INSERT INTO UniqueValuesTable VALUES (@NewValue)
```

Edit: here is a SQL fiddle to show it working

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b87f9/3

As dems pointed out, the operation isn't atomic, so in a multi session situation there could be a PK violation still

Alternative is:

```
INSERT INTO UniqueValuesTable SELECT @NewValue WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT UniqueValue FROM UniqueValuesTable WHERE UniqueValue = @NewValue)
```

Comment: I am not selecting value from table i am inserting value from algo to database.

Comment: Yes and that's what this query does - checks if the value exists already, and if it doesn't it inserts it

Comment: INSERT INTO damidata ("+subject+") VALUES ('" + d[i].ToString() + "') this the query damidata is table name ("+subject+") its a veriable which contains the colum name and ('" + d[i].ToString() + "') these are values gatting from algorithem.

Comment: @Wasif the above select just makes sure you're not inserting duplicates

Comment: Also - making the column the primary key is also a good idea if you are going to be using this query, especially if the table is going to grow considerably. A clustered or regular index seek is generally much faster than a table scan

Comment: @Charleh i tried this but then i got primery key duplication exception at every duplication.

Comment: Ok I've edited to add the link to the SQL fiddle - have a look at that, it shows the query working. You can comment out the 3rd INSERT to see it failing with a primary key violation.

Comment: Not thread safe.  Another session *could* insert a value between the `IF` and the `INSERT`.  Would recommend `INSERT INTO table SELECT @var WHERE NOT EXISTS ()`